# Share dynamic arrayList between activity and service

Tags: android, json

I have an Android application that receives and processes data from a sensor. It includes one main activity class and one service class. The service class is running in the background to receive and save data from sensor. The activity class has a history chart that shows daily average values up to 100 days ago. The lifecycle of the activity and the service should be independent because even when the activity is not running, the service should keep receiving data in the background.

Here is my current implementation. I use shared preference to let the activity access the data from the service. Every time a new data arrives, the service puts the data into arrayList, then serializes the arrayList into an json and saves the json into shared preferences. This is not very efficient because whenever I want to save a new data, I need to get the whole json array from the preference, deserialize it, add the data, and then put the json array back. I know there might be ways to append new json object to a json array string without deserializing it but I haven't figured out how. However even this is doable, I think it is still not efficient because the whole json array would still need to be retrieved from preferences and need allocate memory for this local object. Also, when updating the graph, the whole json will still need to be deserialized.

So I'm thinking of if there is a way to keep the array list as a field of the service and let the main activity access to this field directly. I have done a lot of search but haven't found a good solution. This might sounds a dumb question but any help is appreciated since I'm very new to Android. Also, I wonder in general which implementation is preferred, and if there's a better solution? Thanks for all the helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this would be to use a combination of sqlite and broadcast receivers. Whenever a new data arrives, you'd save it to the sqlite db and fire a broadcast.

Firing a custom broadcast whenever new sensor values are retrieved :

```
Intent newSensorValues = new Intent("NEW_SENSOR_VALUE");
//Add the new sensor values as extras to the intent. 
newSensorValues.putExtra..
...
sendBroadcast(newSensorValues);
//You'll also want to save the data to the sqlite database here. 
saveToDb();
```

Why Fire a Broadcast -- To update the activity from the service, whenever the activity is on the screen.

In your activity where you want to display the graph, you register a `BroadcastReceiver` of the type "NEW_SENSOR_VALUE". Hence, whenever we get a new broadcast, you just use the data passed in the intent to update the map. You'll also unregister the receiver inside `onPause()` of the activity so that the map is not updated when the activity is paused.

```
//Inside onResume() : 
this.registerReceiver(newSensorValueReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    "NEW_SENSOR_VALUE"));

//Inside onPause() :
this.unregisterReceiver(newSensorValueReceiver);

//Broadcast Receiver Class. 
private BroadcastReceiver newSensorValueReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent.getExtra...
        updateGraph();
    }
};
```

Inside `onCreate()` of the Activity :

```
fetchValueFromDb();
updateGraph();
```

The good thing about this approach :

1. You need to access data from the database only when the activity is opened. The rest of the time, whenever a new sensor value is received, you just save it to the sqlite db.
2. Graph is updated in realtime always.

Comment: Thanks @Shivam Verma, your answer is very helpful! As you said I used broadcast receiver to update the latest reading. But if the broadcast receiver is unregistered on pause, should I put the fetchValueFromDb() in onResume() instead of onCreate()? So if there is new data arriving when the app is in the background, it can be immediately reflected on the graph when the app goes to the foreground again.

Comment: ah yes! that'd be better. You've got the idea :)

Comment: Actually another problem I just run into is how should I share the sqlite database between the activity and the service? I have seen people talking about different solutions, such as creating sqliteopenhelper singleton, extending Application class to initiate one helper instance that can be accessed everywhere, or Creating separate helper instance with the same application context. I wonder which solution will work the best?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you not use the sqlite3 to save the data? When a new data arrives, you can save it to sqlite3. When you want to display them in activity, you just need to read from the database and even can choice which records to display.

Comment: whoever thinks @Field.wei is not giving a correct answer and down votes it should give an explanation. And OP is asking another other possible implementation. I think using json to do what OP wants is definitely wrong and using sqlite should be an answer, what's wrong with that? (I upvoted it)

Comment: Thanks @Field.wei! This is definitely a better implementation than json.